# How to remove AD transitive two way trust (ffl and dfl 2016)

Tags: active-directory

How to remove AD transitive two way trust (ffl and dfl 2016) 
What problems should we anticipate after removing the trust?

Comment: domainA.local
domainB.local

Comment: if we encounter problems, does re-establishing the trust resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

> How to remove AD transitive two way trust?

Remove it from Active Directory Domains and Trusts.

> What problems should we anticipate after removing the trust?

The Trust will no longer exist so any operations that require the Trust will no longer work.

> if we encounter problems, does re-establishing the trust resolve it?

Yes.